# Problem with external monitors

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, monitor, vga

I can't connect external monitor to my VGA output.

Graphic card - Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2).

Also can't connect monitor to my dock DVI output.

lshw output

```
*-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 07
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:130 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dffffff
```

xrandr while the VGA is plugged in!!! :

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y 
axis) 280mm x 160mm
1366x768      59.98*+
```

xrandr --verbose showing me eDP-1(build in monitor), DP-1(which i don't have as a connector on laptop), HDMI-1(which i use for second monitor) and HDMI-2(i don't have this port on laptop). Probably HDMI-2 can be a VGA?

Cable and monitor input works good i tried with another laptop.
I used this outputs on Ubuntu 16.04.

Now i tried on Ubuntu 18.04 and latest version of Ubuntu(19.04).

Any idea? Solution?